# How to push commit after checking out previous commit and doing changes in it

Tags: git

I am sort of afraid that my current working code doesn't get screwed.

So let's say I have following commit

```
7abd390c269d4abc9f3208d3c1b0a27ef5ae4162 -> Latest commit 

5488da9335eb51eed274aa9b4a0f8f205643a8e0 -> 2nd commit

a31e310304404eb4452e6465e0a92dd472c5329a -> 1st commit
```

I checked out my **first commit** using

```
git checkout a31e310304404eb4452e6465e0a92dd472c5329a
```

And started doing changes in here. Now I want to commit this and push it to github.

but Things I am trying to avoid 
**Git pull and  Git Merge**

Because at this point of time I have done so many changes.

**Question:** Can anyone tell me if it possible to force push this commit and If yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

What you probably want to do is to create a new branch name for your latest commit, e.g., `git checkout -b newname`.  You can then use this new name for all your work, or use it to remember your commits while you go back to older names and do work.

#### Long

> I checked out my first commit using
>
> ```
> git checkout a31e310304404eb4452e6465e0a92dd472c5329a
> ```

Doing this produces what Git calls a *detached `HEAD`*.  While this may sound scary, it's actually not fatal, it just means that `HEAD` is not attached.

Normally, the special name `HEAD` (written in all capitals, just like this<sup>1</sup>) is attached to some existing branch name.  A branch name, in Git, is how Git keeps track of who's doing what work.  More specifically, the *name itself* stores the raw hash ID of these commits.  So a branch name like `master` or `develop` would store that big ugly hash ID, the `a31e310304404eb4452e6465e0a92dd472c5329a` thing.  That lets you, the human, assign a *meaningful* name to this otherwise seemingly-random thing.

You're not doing the normal thing, and that means you really need to know what you're doing.  Otherwise you'll lose track of your commits, and things will be painful.

---

<sup>1</sup>On Windows and MacOS, you can use `head` in lowercase, but that's something of an an accident / quirk of the system.  It's best to stick with the all-uppercase variant, since the lowercase one won't work on Linux.  If you don't like typing out `HEAD` in all caps, you can use `@` instead, to mean the same thing.

---

#### Commits and branch names

Let's talk a bit more about how Git normally works with branch names, because this part is a little tricky, and yet, is one of the keys to using Git successfully.  The first thing to understand is that Git itself does not care very much about these names: they are mostly for humans to use.  Git mostly cares about the hash IDs, those big ugly strings of letters and numbers.  Those uniquely identify each commit, and commits are the reason that Git exists at all.  So they're what Git cares about.

Let's look at a really tiny, almost-new repository, with just three commits in it.  These three commits will each have their own unique hash ID, but to save us a lot of headache, I'll use single uppercase letters for them instead.  I'll call the first commit ever made `A`, the second commit `B`, and the third one `C`.

Each commit stores a complete snapshot of a source tree, along with some *metadata*, which is just a fancy word for the stuff `git log` can print *about* the commit: who made it and when, and what log message they entered for it.  The metadata also includes the raw hash ID of the commit's *parent* commit, which is the commit that *was* in place *when* the person made that commit.

In other words, each commit *points back* to its previous commit.  So let's draw that:

```
A  <-B  <-C
```

Commit `A`, being the very first commit, has *no* parent, because it can't.  But commit `B` remembers that `A` was the commit when `B` was made, so `B` points back to `A`.  Likewise, commit `C` remembers for us that `B` was its parent, so `C` points back to `B`.

What we—and Git—need at this point is a way to find the big ugly hash ID for commit `C`.  This is where branch names come in: the branch name `master` can hold the big ugly unique hash ID for `C`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

We say that the branch name, `master`, *points to* the *last* commit in the chain.  We use the branch name to get the hash ID, and that lets us (via Git) get to commit `C`.  Commit has `B`'s hash inside it, so from `C` we can find `B`, and from `B`, we can find `A`.  `A` has no parent, so we can stop at this point.

Now, we if we only have the one branch name, it's pretty simple.  We `git checkout master`, which gets us commit `C`.  Then we make some changes, `git add` our changed files, and run `git commit`.  This packages up the new snapshot, adds our own name and the current time, adds our log message, saves `C`'s hash ID, and makes a new commit, which now gets a new, unique, big ugly hash ID, and now the key step happens: *Git writes the new hash ID into the name `master`:*

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

But what if we have *two* branch names?  Let's create a new branch name now:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, develop
```

Right now, both names store the *same* hash ID, the one for commit `D`.  Now Git needs to know *which branch name to update*.  So to do that, Git attaches `HEAD` to one of them, whichever one we give to `git checkout`.  For instance:

```
git checkout master

A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

but:

```
git checkout develop

A--B--C--D   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

Either way, we're starting from commit `D`.  The difference is which branch *name* changes when we make new commit `E`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The thing to remember here is this: **Whenever we add a new commit, Git makes the new commit have the previously-current commit as its parent.  Then Git writes the *new* commit's ID into the *branch name* to which `HEAD` is attached.**

Note that the `git checkout` step does *two* things:

- it selects the commit that the branch name points-to; and
- it attaches `HEAD` to that branch name.

Here, the first point did not matter only because both `master` and `develop` pointed to the *same* commit.

#### A detached HEAD is almost the same, but there's no branch name involved

If you `git checkout` a commit by its raw hash ID, then Git still selects that commit to be the current commit, but this time, it *doesn't* attach `HEAD` to a branch name.  Let's say, for instance, that you pick the hash ID of commit `C`.  There is no branch name pointing to `C`, so Git has to do this instead:

```
          E   <-- develop
         /
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C   <-- HEAD
```

All we did here was to swing `D` and `E` up out of the way so that we can draw `HEAD` in pointing directly to commit `C`.  What Git did here was to write the raw hash ID into the name `HEAD`, rather than having the branch name in `HEAD`.  (If you want, you can look at the file `.git/HEAD`: it either contains a raw hash ID like this, or, if it's attached to a branch, contains the text `ref: refs/heads/branch`.)

Now we can make a new commit as usual, by editing files, running `git add` as needed, and running `git commit`.  Git collects our commit message as usual, and makes a new commit as usual.  The new commit's parent commit is the current commit—commit `C`—whose hash ID is in the `HEAD` file.  Then, instead of writing the new commit's hash ID to the *branch name* in the `HEAD` file, Git just writes the new commit's ID into `HEAD` directly:

```
          E   <-- develop
         /
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C--F   <-- HEAD
```

If you go on to make two more commits, the process simply repeats:

```
          E   <-- develop
         /
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C--F--G--H   <-- HEAD
```

Note that Git can easily find commit `H` right now, because its hash ID is in the `HEAD` file.  From `H`, Git can find `G` and `F` (and then `C` and so on too).  But if you `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop`, for instance, Git will make commit `D` or `E` the current commit and *will write the branch name into the `HEAD` file, losing `H`'s hash ID*.

If you save the hash ID somewhere, you can still work with it, for a while.  Git tries not to throw out un-findable commits like this for a while.<sup>2</sup>  But it becomes hard to find, lost in a sea of nearly-identical commits distinguished mainly by their seemingly-random hash IDs.  The best thing to do is to give it a name.

---

<sup>2</sup>This lasts at least 30 days by default, using the *reflog* for `HEAD`.  The reflog contains all the hash IDs that `HEAD` named over the last 30 to 90 days, or longer, depending on a number of details that I won't go into here as this is already too long. :-)

---

#### Giving a name to a commit hash

What you probably want to do now, then, is to assign a name to remember the hash ID `H`.  This is what branch names—and tag names, for that matter—are for.  If you create a *new* branch name right now, by default, it will point to the *current commit*:

```
git branch xyzzy

          E   <-- develop
         /
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C--F--G--H   <-- HEAD, xyzzy
```

Note that this didn't *attach* `HEAD` to the name `xyzzy`.  After creating the name, you can `git checkout xyzzy` to tell Git to switch from commit `H`, where `HEAD` points now, to commit `H`, where `xyzzy` points.  That switch does nothing, but now the second part of `git checkout` applies, and Git attaches `HEAD` to the name `xyzzy`:

```
          E   <-- develop
         /
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C--F--G--H   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
```

You can do both of these at once using `git checkout -b xyzzy`: that creates `xyzzy`, pointing to the current commit, and at the same time, attaches `HEAD` to the new name `xyzzy`.

Once you have done this, you now have a *name* for your commits.  It's now possible to use `git push` to send the commits to another Git repository, telling that other Git repository to set *its* `xyzzy` to point to commit `H` (whatever `H`'s actual hash ID is).

When the other Git repository gets `H`, it also gets `G` and `F` and, if required, `C` and `B` and even `A` (assuming this particular graph drawing is correct).  Essentially, `git push` sends *all* the commits that are contained in—or *reachable from* (see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/))—the branch, unless the other Git already has them.  Then your Git has their Git set some name, usually the same name, to remember the *last* commit, the way branches do.

If you don't wish to save the two `F` and `G` snapshots and their commit metadata, it's now time to use `git rebase` or similar to rewrite some commits, but that's a topic for another question (and there are lots of answers on StackOverflow already about this).

Comment: This is a really good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you force push your new commit, you will loose the other 2 commits that are online (I assume that you ave a new local commit, no reason why not).

Create a new local branch if you don't want to merge just now. But you will "have to" pull what there is online, and then merge.

Pulling and merging won't destroy your local merge, but you have to merge if you stay on the same branch because there can be only one head commit per named branch with git.